# Question on convergence of difference between two real sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> Let $\{x_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ and $\{y_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ be two sequences of real numbers such that $x_n^3 - y_n^3 \to 0.$ Can we always conclude that $x_n - y_n \to 0\ $?

I think it is true. But I can't able to prove it. I tried by factorizing $$x_n^3 - y_n^3 = (x_n - y_n) (x_n^2 + x_n y_n + y_n^2).$$

Now how do I proceed? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Just as an aside: The above is not true if we allow $x_n$ and $y_n$ to be complex-valued. For example, take the constant sequences $x_n := 1$ and $y_n := \exp(2\pi\iota/3)$.

Comment: Another thing that is obvious is that if either $x_n$ or $y_n$ have a limit, then it can be shown the other too and the limits are the same. So, you need to have sequences without limits if a counterexample is to exist.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Suppose that you *don't* have $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n-y_n=0$. Then there is some $r>0$ such that $|x_n-y_n|\geqslant r$ for infinitely many $n$'s. For each such $n$, you have\begin{align}x_n^{\,2}+x_ny_n+y_n^{\,2}&=\frac34(x_n+y_n)^2+\frac14(x_n-y_n)^2\\&\geqslant\frac{r^2}4\end{align}and therefore\begin{align}\left|x_n^{\,3}-y_n^{\,3}\right|&=\left(x_n^{\,2}+x_ny_n+y_n^{\,2}\right)|x_n-y_n|\\&\geqslant\frac{r^2}4\times r\\&=\frac{r^3}4.\end{align}So, you also don't have $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n^{\,3}-y_n^{\,3}=0$.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.**

---

For $x, y \in \Bbb R$, we have $$x^2 + xy + y^2 \ge \frac{3}{4}y^2.$$
(Complete the square.)

Let $c := \frac{3}{4}$.

Thus, we get $$|x^3 - y^3| \ge c|x - y|y^2 \ge 0.$$

Now, since $x_n^3 - y_n^3 \to 0$, Sandwich Theorem tells us that $$|x_n - y_n|y_n^2 \to 0$$ and the same with $x_n$ instead of $y_n$.

To conclude, we get

$$|x_n - y_n|(x_n^2 + y_n^2) \to 0. \qquad (*)$$

Now, note that $$\sqrt{2}\sqrt{x_n^2 + y_n^2} \ge |x_n| + |y_n| \ge |x_n - y_n|$$
and thus, plugging it in $(*)$ gives
$$0 \le \frac{1}{2}|x_n - y_n|^3 \le |x_n - y_n|(x_n^2 + y_n^2) \to 0.$$

Sandwich theorem now gives gives $$|x_n - y_n|^3 \to 0.$$

Thus, $$|x_n - y_n| \to 0,$$ as desired.

Comment: At last where did you apply Sandwich theorem? What do you mean by previous limit? I don't get your point. You apply two inequalities to get the last sequence of inequalities. One is the triangle inequality and the other one is Cauchy-Schwarz. Upto that part I understand. But then where to apply Sandwich?

Comment: @Fanatics: I have edited it to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $\displaystyle x_n^3 - y_n^3 = \int\limits_{y_n}^{x_n} dt\ \dfrac{t^2}{3},$ this converges to zero in absolute value, so
$$
|x_n^3 - y_n^3| \geq \frac{1}{3}\min(x_n^2, y_n^2) |x_n - y_n|.
$$
If either $x_{n_k}^3$ or $y_{n_k}^3$ converges to any number $a^3$ (for some subsequence $(n_k)$), then $x_{n_k}$ and $y_{n_k}$ will both converge to $a$ by the continuity of the cubic root. Further, we know that a sequence converges if and only every subsequence of it converges, and we have already dealt with the case of subsequences where the $(x_{n_k})$ or $(y_{n_k})$ converges. So we can safely assume , by renaming the index, that $x_n$ and $y_n$ do not have subsequences that converge to zero (in fact, to any number). *A fortiori* there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\min(x_n^2, y_n^2) > \delta$ and the result follows. Q.E.D.

**Bonus.** We can also prove it with Taylor's theorem. Since $y_n^3 = x_n^3 + h_n$ (with $h_n \to 0$) and we can assume $|x_n| >  \delta > 0$ for all $n,$ we see that
$$
y_n = x_n + \dfrac{1}{3(c_n)^{\frac{2}{3}}} h_n
$$
with $c_n$ lying between $x_n^3$ and $x_n^3 + h_n,$ since $h_n$ converges to zero, we can assume $n$ large enough so that $|c_n| > \dfrac{\delta}{2}.$ In any case, we wrote $y_n = x_n + e_n$ with $e_n \to 0$ and we are done.

Comment: While I like the out of the box thinking with the integral, the logic is wrong later on. yn could be the constant zero sequence, so you cannot safely assume that xn and yn do not have subsequences that converge to zero.

Comment: If $y_n$ converged to some number $y$ (in particular, for the constant zero sequence), then $x_n = \sqrt[3]{y_n} \to \sqrt[3]{y}$ by continuity. So, you can assume that $y_n$ does not converge. Since this is true for every subsequence, you assume every subsequence does not converge.

Comment: @WillM.: I don't understand the logic behind passing down to subsequence. For example, one could have $x_n = y_n = (-1)^n - 1$.  Neither $x_n$ nor $y_n$ converge but they do have a subsequence converging to $0$.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani I don't want to sound rude but you are not raising any interesting issue: if $x_n = y_n,$ then $x_n - y_n = 0$ and we can discard those terms. I will add a line in hopes you see it more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $x_n^3 - y_n^3\to 0$ and $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous. Then $f(x_n^3) - f(y_n^3)\to 0.$ So we're done if we can show $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R.$

To do this, note that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R,$ hence it is uniformly continuous on $[-1,1].$ Also $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[1,\infty).$  This follows from the MVT because, as you can verify, $|f'| \le 1/3$ on $[1,\infty).$ The same estimate holds on $(-\infty,-1].$ It follows that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(-\infty,-1]\cup[-1,1]\cup [1,\infty) =\mathbb R,$ and we're done.

Comment: I liked this one a lot! This is essentially the same as the proof by Taylor's theorem I gave above (and the proof by integral I also gave is essentially the same as the most upvoted answer).

Answer (score 1):

For all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ ,$a^2+b^2 +ab \ge \frac{1}{4}(a-b)^2$, hence $$|a^3-b^3| =|a-b||a^2+ab+b^2| \ge \frac{1}{4}|a-b|^3$$
Besides $ x_n^3-y_n^3 \rightarrow 0$ means that $ \lim |x_n^3-y_n^3| =0$, so by squeeze theorem, $\lim \frac{1}{4}|x_n-y_n|^3=0$, or
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} |x_n-y_n|=0 $$